# Keeping cell value when source data is deleted

Tags: google-sheets-api

I tried to link a cell value from another sheet A to my current sheet B. The issue is that the value from sheet A will be reset each day, is there anyway to not delete the value in sheet B (which was linked) after value sheet A being reset?
Thank you.

I tried indirect but i did not help